# Allow special characters and symbols to be part of route parameter

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-7, laravel-routing

I am trying to send a s3 link of an image to an image viewer, the link has special characters like ?, & and =, I want send the link to the route as a route parameter and can't find a way to make the route parameter accepts special characters like ('?, /, &, _, %').

current route: Route::get('show/360/{link}', 'SiteSectionController@show360')->name('site.sections.show360')->where('link', '.*'); the link parameter accpets slashes (/) but not the query string.

when i dd($link) it's printed without the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the controller and it solved the problem, the problem was that laravel treats the query string of the url as a request query string not as a url segment.

```
$query = $request->fullUrl();
$query = substr($query, strpos($query, 'https'));
return view('viewer')->with(['link' => $query]);
```